# Mips instructions mthi and mtlo into hex?

Tags: mips

I am in the process of writing a utility to convert a mips instruction into its hex (4 bytes) format.  Everything was going ok with instructions such as ADD, etc.  But with mthi and mtlo, there is a different in the output I am getting compare to what is expected.  I am not sure what exact version of mips this is.

Here is what I am getting:

```
mthi    $t2  = 01400011
mthi    $s0  = 02000011
mtlo    $t8  = 03000013
mtlo    $a3  = 00e00013
```

Here is what I am getting:

mthi    $t2

```
1010 00000 00000 00000 010001
```

Does anyone know how the inner bits are being calculated and what version of mips that is?  Thanks.

Comment: Who is telling you that `014B0151` is correct for `mthi $t2`? As far as I can tell that matches neither the MIPS32 nor MIPS64 documentation from MIPS Technologies. You should ask the person who told you that `014B0151` is correct to clarify which documentation you're supposed to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Information from "See MIPS Run", for all MIPS ISA it covers (up through MIPS IV) there is no difference in the MIPS32 instruction.

This is the format for mfhi, mtlo, mfhi, mtlo (mfhi/mflo included for comparison and completeness)

```
bit:     31-26  25-21  20-16   15-11  10-6  5-0 
mfhi rd    0      0      0      rd     0     16 
mthi rs    0      rs     0      0      0     17 
mflo rd    0      0      0      rd     0     18 
mtlo rs    0      rs     0      0      0     19
```

So mthi $t2 (register #10)

```
mthi $t2   000000 01010 00000 00000 00000  01001
```

Comment: That's the encoding for `MFHI $t2`.

Comment: @markgz mixed up a copy and paste when formatting my answer, it should be correct now. Please do point out any errors.

Answer (score 0):

The MIPS 32R2 encoding of MTHI rs is binary 000000 sssss 000 0000 0000 0000 010001.

So `MTHI $t2` is binary 000000 01010 000 0000 0000 0000 010001